# Can't declare Session variable in asp.net sharepoint page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session, sharepoint

So I need to store some data on my page (webpart) in variables after post request.

But when I try to declare it for example `Session["test value"] = someValue;`Visual studio just don't recognize `Session`. I checked namespcses, wrote probably everything that is possible but it still can't see Session.

What am I doing wrong? 
And if it is not possible for some reason in my case, how should I save Variables after post request? Static class is not an option since he in only 1 for all users and I need to store different data for different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [HttpContext.Current.Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you need

Example of usage:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
```

Store data

```
context.Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
```

Retrieve data

```
firstName = (string)(context.Session["FirstName"]);
```

Comment: This also doesn't work.  'The type or namespace name 'Httpcontext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Do you have reference to System.Web.Dll? It should be, or you can add it manually.

Comment: Yes I have, just checked.

Comment: so, you have to add ```using System.Web;``` in using section.

Comment: I didn't saw that you edited your answer HttpContext.Current.Session  and didn't understand right. But It still doesn't work because I can't just call it like that, HttpContext should be set to something?

Comment: Okay I was dumb and tried to declare it right in beginning of the code, not function :) Thx anyway it helped me to understand how it is working.